# Ubuntu openVPN TCP no internet, UDP works. Win7 works on both TCP/UDP with same settings

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, tcp, openvpn

I've recently purchased a VPN service which I'm connecting to with openVPN.

On Windows 7 I can connect on both UDP and TCP settings, but when I'm trying the same thing on Ubuntu 13.04, it gives me `Initialization Sequence Completed` but only UDP gives me access to webpages.

When I'm trying to connect to a webpage with TCP it just keep loading with nothing happening

I've tried many settings from around the net which also includes commands for `iptables`.

I've also tried importing my settings in `network-manager-openvpn, network-manager-openvpn-gnome` but this gives me the error `"VPN-NAME" Failed because of invalid VPN secret`

I'm pretty sure that the problem is somewhere in the Ubuntu configuration, but here is my openVPN config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote vpn.host.here 443
reneg-sec 0
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth ta.key 1
auth-user-pass
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 4
tun-ipv6
keepalive 5 30
```

I don't know what information or logs is usable to fix this problem, but I will add it to the question when needed.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

BTW I can't use the UDP method because the port used there is not open on the network I'm going to use it on. It need to be port 80 or 443.

Comment: have you already unlocked the system keyring at the time you attempt to start the VPN connection? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1193786

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm not quite sure what you mean. I've never been prompt to unlock the keyring on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: perhaps it has changed then. I gave up on ubuntu when unity came around, so can't tell you for sure. it is the leading answer when you google 'openvpn invalid VPN secret' though.

Comment: When i've searched for a solution this fix has come up multiple times: http://alexmufatti.it/2011/02/14/networkmanager-openvpn-secrets-error/ but it does not work either.

Comment: @FrankThomas But I'm able to connect to the VPN with command line so it should be possible to make it work without network-manager-openvpn and network-manager-openvpn-gnome